# Regular expression to match one of two video ID's in a Google Video URL

Tags: c#, regex

I need to grab the video ID from a Google Video URL. There are two different types of URLs that I need to be able to match:

> http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=**-3498228245415745977**#

where I need to be able to match `-3498228245415745977` (note the dash; -), and

> video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-3498228245415745977#docid=**2728972720932273543**

where I need to match `2728972720932273543`. Is there any good regular expression that can match this?

This is what I've got so far: `@"docid=(-?\d{19}+)"` since the video ID seems to be 19 characters except when it's prefixed with the dash.

I'm using C# (of which I have very little experience) if that changes anything.

P.s. I would also appreciate you review my regular expressions for YouTube (`@"[\?&]v=([^&#])";`), RedTube (`@"/(\d{1,6})"`) and Vimeo (`@"/(\d*)"`).

I do not expect users to enter the full URL and thus do not match the `^http://\\.?sitename+\\.\\w{2,3}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of RegEx uses what is called negative lookahead to make sure that there is not any part of the string after the match that contains #docid:

```
docid=(-?\d{19}(?!\#docid=))
```

the `(?!\#docid=)` is the negative lookahead part of the RegEx. If you want to know more about it you could look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Hope this helps you

EDIT:
  If you  haven't already gotten it you should get ["The Regulator 2.0"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/) from sourceforge. Its an Design and testing tool for Regular Expressions. I find it very helpful when I develope regular expressions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with negative lookaheads, but would that expression match the "2728972720932273543" (latter) part of "video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-3498228245415745977#docid=2728972720932273543"?

Comment: yes it would. It wouldn't match the -3498228245415745977 part because there is a "#docid=" coming right after it, so it skips that part and then finds the latter part that was also matched by your RegEx. 
So the "only" thing a negative lookahead does is make sure the match is not followed be a given expression.

Answer (score 0):

use this RE:

```
docid=-([0-9]*)
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => docid=-3498228245415745977
    [1] => 3498228245415745977
)
```

I had tested it in Java, PHP, awk, perl.